# How does one get rails3 to display initial values in form fields of the new action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, default-value, form-for

The Rails3 form_for view helper displays current values on edit.

I would like to populate the model with some initial values on create.  Not the same initial value every time, but actually copy some of the values from the last record stored.

When I do this, and use the form_for helper to construct the form, none of the values appear.

It looks like form_for does not emit the value attributes for input fields of a model not yet saved?  But I wouldn't save the newly created model before displaying the form because: 1. it would not validate, 2. that complicates the semantics of canceling, 3. navigating away from the form would leave an unintentionally saved record.

How can I get a form rendered from the new action to display some dynamic defaults?

Seriously.  I've been reading all day without an answer.  This seems like there ought to be an easy solution that I'm missing.

---

The problem came from the initialization code in the model.  The controller had

```
def new
  @post = Post.new
  @post.initFromLast
end
```

The model had

```
def initFromLast
  last_post = Post.last
  title = last_post.title
  summary = last_post.summary
end
```

The model needed

```
def initFromLast
  last_post = Post.last
  write_attribute(:title, last_post.title)
  write_attribute(:summary, last_post.summary)
end
```

Ruby apparently interpreted the first form as assignments to local variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this in your controller:

```
def new
  last_post = Post.last
  @post = Post.new
  @post.title = last_post.title
  @post.summary = last_post.summary
  ...
end
```

... then in your view you should have something like:

```
form_for @post do |form|
  form.text_field :title
  form.text_area :summary
  ...
```

The form ***should*** have the initial values even if the record is unsaved.

Comment: So I thought.  And that does in fact work.  The trouble was from elsewhere.